# ITK not building with VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, installation, itk

I followed the steps on this [link](http://qtitkvtkhelp.blogspot.in/2012/11/itk-installation-for-msvc.html) to install and configure InsightToolkit (ITK) 4.5.0 for MSVS 2010 as I'm trying to use it with VC++. I followed them till step #10 (building ALL_BUILD) but I can't see any building progress.. VS only indicate that build started then nothing.. I let it work for about 2 hours but didn't give me any sign of progressing or completion. After 3 hours I had to cancel the build. I'm not sure what is causing this problem and I was hoping that anyone can help me with it..
I used cMake 2.8.12.2 to configure and generate ITK source and you can see the output it gave me on this  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxrotkiN79rLdnEwUlpCd2MyMTQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Your build has been stopped due to this error: Could NOT find Perl (missing:  PERL_EXECUTABLE) Configuring done.
It seems strange to me (I never had this problem), but maybe CMake needs to execute some Perl script for the Configuration step, and it's not properly configured in your system.

Comment: I use cmake --build instead of opening the solution in visual studio. This works every time for me which is dozens of times since I have used ITK since 2008 on windows and use multiple machines for development at work and at home.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the similar situation when I build ITK last time..In my condition, configuring ITK using CMake, I select the "BUILD_EXAMPLES" and "BUILD_TESTING", there will be more than 600 projects when I open ITK.sln using VS2010, building it lead to no sign of progressing and completion, I don't know why either...Afterwards, I configured ITK again without selecting "BUILD_EXAMPLES" and "BUILD_TESTING", after "Generate" and open it with VS2010, there are about 200 projects, and compiling this ITK.sln, it can work smoothly..

Comment: I normally turn off BUILD_EXAMPLES and BUILD_TESTING since each of these take a long time even on a 12 threaded PC with SSDs.